# How to monitor JVM with JRE only

Tags: java, jvm

I have a Centos7 server and I want to monitor the JVM in order to identify performance issue but I have only JRE installed on the prod environment as follows:

[image]

Based on the research I saw there were some tool available such as Java Mission Control but it is only available with JDK but I have JRE installed. Any idea what open source tool I can use to monitor the jvm on centos with only JRE installed?

Comment: If you can install third-party Open Source tools, why can't you just install a JDK?

Comment: OK but I will need to stop the live server in order to install the jdk, and is it good idea to have JDK on live environement?

Comment: "*I will need to stop the live server in order to install the jdk*" Why?

Comment: my apologies,i thought I had to stop the server uninstall the jre and then install the jdk

Comment: First: no, you can connect tools from the JDK to a JVM running in a JRE. The JVM itself is the same one. Second: The concept of a "JRE" has been basically removed in more recent Java releases for various reasons, so yes, having "a JDK" on a production environment is *probably* acceptable by some metrics. At least it's no worse (in my opinion) than installing alternative monitoring tools that are just as powerful/intrusive than what the JDK provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jattach gives you access to a few powerful tools, namely jcmd which you can then use to run various diagnostics commands against the java app.
Works with plain JRE - check https://github.com/apangin/jattach

See also https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jcmd.html